# Cannot clone object error when using Keras and scikit-learn for classification (Trying to Add cross validation to a working model)( Train split works)

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, sequential

***I have an existing NN model (Sequential model) with a train split test. I need to add cross-validation to my dataset; upon implementation of cross-validation, I get the following error.***

```
TypeError: Cannot clone object '<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001B5D2100108>' (type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

The code for the model is as follows when I add the cross-validation to an existing train-test-split which was working.

**Dataset Spliting**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_val_predict # For Cross validation I have added this
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=101)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_val_predict # For Cross validation I have added this
from sklearn import metrics # For Cross validation, I have added this
```

**Scaling Data**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

**Creating the Model**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout
```

**Training the Model**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=70,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))

model.add(Dense(units=15,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))

model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=25)
model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=600,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1,
          callbacks=[early_stop]
          )
```

**This is where adding the cross-validation predictor gives and error**

```
predictions = cross_val_predict(model, X_test, y_test, cv=3) # for cross validation ** (model, df, y, cv=3)
model_loss = pd.DataFrame(model.history.history)
model_loss.plot()
```

**The complete Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    796             try:
--> 797                 tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    798             except queue.Empty:

~\anaconda3\lib\queue.py in get(self, block, timeout)
    166                 if not self._qsize():
--> 167                     raise Empty
    168             elif timeout is None:

Empty: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-2b7d023d5ca4> in <module>
----> 1 predictions = cross_val_predict(model, X_test, y_test, cv=3) # for cross validation ** (model, df, y, cv=3)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_predict(estimator, X, y, groups, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, method)
    753     prediction_blocks = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_predict)(
    754         clone(estimator), X, y, train, test, verbose, fit_params, method)
--> 755         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    756 
    757     # Concatenate the predictions

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1002             # remaining jobs.
   1003             self._iterating = False
-> 1004             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    806                 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
    807 
--> 808                 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    809                 if len(islice) == 0:
    810                     return False

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    753     prediction_blocks = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_predict)(
    754         clone(estimator), X, y, train, test, verbose, fit_params, method)
--> 755         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    756 
    757     # Concatenate the predictions

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     65                             "it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator "
     66                             "as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods."
---> 67                             % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
     68     klass = estimator.__class__
     69     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
```

***The Type Error is***

```
TypeError: Cannot clone object '<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001577B632148>' (type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Point is that your model is not a *[sklearn estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#)* as the error suggests (in particular, it lacks of the `.get_params()` method), while `cross_val_predict()` requires a *sklearn estimator* to be passed to it.

A way to get around this is to wrap your Keras model in an object that mimics a regular sklearn estimator via a [`scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier`](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/generated/scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier.html#scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier) object. Once you've defined your `KerasClassifier` you can use it as a classical *sklearn classifier* and therefore pass it to `cross_val_predict()`.

Here's a working example that starts from your snippet:

```
!pip install scikeras

from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=70, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=101)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=70,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))

model.add(Dense(units=15,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))

model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=25)
model.fit(x=X_train, 
      y=y_train, 
      epochs=600,
      validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1,
      callbacks=[early_stop]
)

# define the KerasClassifier object and use it in cross_val_predict
keras_clf = KerasClassifier(model = model, optimizer="adam", epochs=100, verbose=0)

predictions = cross_val_predict(keras_clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are getting following error due to above statement: Cannot clone object <keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x7f93ddc5d1d0>, as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter layers

Change the layers from array of list to array of tuple: layers => [(20,), (45, 30, 15), (40, 20)]
Don't forget to add comma after (20,) otherwise another error/warning will appear - FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable Because single tuple without comma is treated as int.

Comment: Sorry I do not follow can you explain it a bit further.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to use Keras parameters

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).