# gridSearchCV fails to estimate parameters

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to do some tests with GridSearch, but I have this error, could you tell me why?

**in clone raise TypeError("Cannot clone object '%s' (type %s): "
TypeError: Cannot clone object '<keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f330fe610a0>' (type <class 'keras.engine.functional.Functional'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' method.**

My code:

Model:

```
from keras import backend as K, regularizers
from keras.engine.training import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, \
BatchNormalization, Activation, Input
import ModelLib


class Cifar100_Model(ModelLib.ModelLib):
def build_classifier_model(self, dataset, n_classes=5,
                           activation='elu', dropout_1_rate=0.25,
                           dropout_2_rate=0.5,
                           reg_factor=50e-4, bias_reg_factor=None, batch_norm=False):
     
    n_classes = dataset.n_classes
    print(n_classes)
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    l2_reg = regularizers.l2(reg_factor) #K.variable(K.cast_to_floatx(reg_factor))
    l2_bias_reg = None
    if bias_reg_factor:
        l2_bias_reg = regularizers.l2(bias_reg_factor) #K.variable(K.cast_to_floatx(bias_reg_factor))

    # input image dimensions
    h, w, d = 32, 32, 3

    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        input_shape = (d, h, w)
    else:
        input_shape = (h, w, d)

    # input image dimensions
    x = input_1 = Input(shape=input_shape)

    x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=dropout_1_rate)(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=dropout_1_rate)(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=dropout_1_rate)(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=dropout_1_rate)(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(units=512, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation=activation)(x)


    x = Dropout(rate=dropout_2_rate)(x)
    x = Dense(units=n_classes, kernel_regularizer=l2_reg, bias_regularizer=l2_bias_reg)(x)
    if batch_norm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[input_1], outputs=[x])
    return model
```

Code test:
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import models.cifar100_model

```
def load_model():
  return models.cifar100_model.Cifar100_Model()

def get_params(self, deep = True):
  return {"learning rate" self.learning_rate}

model_lib = load_model() 
     
model = model_lib.build_classifier_model(dataset)


x_train = dataset.x_train
y_train = dataset.y_train_labels
learning_rate = [0.01, 0.1]
param_grid = dict(learning_rate = learning_rate)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3, scoring='accuracy') 
gridResult = grid.fit(x_train,y_train)
print(gridResult.best_params_)
```

Comment: Dataset is Cifar100                                                                                                             
 dataset = datasets.cifar100_subset.Cifar100_Subset(supeclass_idx=15, normalize=False)

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113176/cannot-clone-object-error-when-using-keras-and-scikit-learn-for-classification/73114463#73114463 may help