# Cannot clone Keras object on cross_val_predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, clone

I am implementing an MLP to perform a regression on a dataset.
I am using a custom loss function that I defined on the line model.compile():

```
input_dim = 24
output_dim = 1

# Define the Spearman rank correlation coefficient as a custom loss function
def spearman_rank_correlation(y_true, y_pred):
    corr = tfp.stats.correlation(y_true, y_pred)
    return -corr

def rank_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    true_ranks = tf.argsort(tf.argsort(y_true, axis=1), axis=1)
    pred_ranks = tf.argsort(tf.argsort(y_pred, axis=1), axis=1)
    return tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(true_ranks, pred_ranks)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=input_dim),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim, activation='linear')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tfp.stats.correlation)

model.fit(X_train_fr, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)

pred_train = cross_val_predict(model, X_train_fr, Y_train, cv=5)
```

My issue is that when I use cross_val_predict(), I get the error

```
Cannot clone object '<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x0000021DFE729190>' (type    <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' method.
```

Do you have any idea of where that could come from?

Comment: You need to use KerasClassifier to pass a Keras model to scikit learn functions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113176/cannot-clone-object-error-when-using-keras-and-scikit-learn-for-classification/73114463#73114463